# Kusto logstash update syslogs in real time

Tags: azure, logstash, azure-data-explorer

I hope everyone is doing great.

I do have a question about azure data explorer and logstash.

I followed this Microsoft tutorial to configure a azure data explorer with Kusto and logstash.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-logstash

I created a azure data explorer, created a table for the data. on the other side I pinned up a virtual machine, installed logstash and configured all the minimum required to forward syslogs to azure data explorer.

Everything works just fine and I don't have any problem, but there is one step that is bugging me a bit and would like some clarifications.

I wanted to test this project with real time syslogs coming from my virtual machine.

so I configured `conf` file for logstash as follow:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 514
 }
}
output {
  kusto {
    path => "/tmp/kusto/%{+YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.txt"
    ingest_url => "my-ingest-url"
    app_id => "app-id"
    app_key => "secret"
    app_tenant => "tenant"
    database => "db"
    table => "table"
    json_mapping => "mapping"
 }
}
```

To test this I installed kiwi syslogs generator, and start sending data once a second. Everything works fine but data-explorer takes up to 10min to show those syslogs.

Based on my understanding and configuration file. for each syslog forwarded, kusto creates a file in tmp folder, writes that syslog and than closes the file.

```
path => "/tmp/kusto/%{+YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.txt"
```

after this process it takes 10min before to see it visualised in my data-explorer.

This is an issue for me because what I would like to do, is to have a azure function that triggers every 12hrs and targets all the data since that specific moment without leaving any data outside because is still in pending.

I don't know if I explained my problem properly, but please if you have any question don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 10 minutes it takes to show up in Kusto, this is likely due to the [ingestionbatching policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/batching-policy) on the table where the default batching period is five minutes. If you want the data to show up faster you can set the MaximumBatchingTimeSpan to less than this, where 10 seconds is the minimum, please note that having too small of a batching window may have an adverse impact on the cluster performance.

I am not sure how the Azure function relates to the scenario can you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry for the basic question. How can I set the MaximumBatchungTimeSpan?. The azure function will run a python sdk code to query this syslog and output a csv file to a database. That's all what this azure function has to do. But when I run it, the logs  outputted to the csv file doesn't match the actual one on data-source, due to the delay as I mentioned. Thank you so much for replying

Comment: Avnera, Thank you so much for your advice. I used the Maximumbatching and in fact  now it does refresh every 5sec. Thank you again